# How to prevent 2 threads from overwriting value?

Tags: python, class, object, parallel-processing

I was trying to run a operation which has varied wait time to be executed parallely in threads. In the operation i am setting a value and waiting for operation to finish, and calling another function. But the thread that started after waiting is overwriting the value for all other threads.

I tried using thread.local method but not working

```py
import threading
class temp:
    def __init__(self):
        self.temp = {}
    def set_data(self,data):
        self.temp['data'] = data
    def get_data(self):
        return self.temp['data']

def process(t):        
    # print(t)                                         
    # mydata = threading.local()
    print('before sleep',threading.current_thread(),t.get_data())
    # sleep(random.randint(0,1)*10)
    print('after sleep',threading.current_thread(),t.get_data())

if __name__=='__main__':
    threads = []
    test = []
    for i in range(0,4):
        t = temp()
        t.set_data(i)
        threads.append(threading.Thread(target=process, args=(t,)))         
        threads[-1].start()
    for t in threads:
        t.join()
```

I expect the value that i sent to the thread remain the same after wait time. But the threads are interfering and giving random output

Comment: I wouldn't matter if you are using `Thread`s or not. By having `temp={}` as a class variable, there is only one copy of it and any attempt to update it will write to the same `dict`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make `temp` an instance variable of class `temp`. Put it in `__init__` as `self.temp = {}`.